# GAS webapp fail silently, how to trace error?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

<< Update >>
Was required implicitly set all variables IN link:
`?phone={ct_phone}&status={ct_status}&record_url={ct_record_url} It will send 3 parameters {ct_phone}&status&record_url`
Otherwise it send nothing:

```
  {"parameters":{},"contentLength":-1,"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","queryString":""}
```

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on troubleshooting:  [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting?hl=en)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `it still running in some way, and not give any new row in document`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it? And, I think that when your php is run, your Google Apps Script append the values to the sheet. So for example, when you redeployed the Web Apps as new version and test it again, what result will you obtain? But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.

Comment: Has delete all versions, redeploy, test from my php - new row with values, and nothing from  https://zvonok.com/ - no error, no new row, thank for comment.

Comment: Hello there @SiegfridHaberman! I tried to replicate this issue but I failed. I suspect that this is because the problem lies on the Zvonok side, instead of the API side. To test that, could you please share a script that works without Zvonok?

Comment: Was required to set variables in postback-link: ?phone={ct_phone}&status={ct_status}&record_url={ct_record_url}, They take this, processing(set actual data  instead variables) and then execute, It was Client and my mistake.